# Разбить строку на подстроки фиксированной длины без PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть строка `123456789qwerty`.

Как мне в рамках запроса разделить ее на подстроки по 5 символов?

Comment: т.е. разделить на несколько строк по 5 символов ?

Comment: ну как вариант человека ничего в регулярках не понимающего 
  `WITH adc as (
SELECT '12345_789563324_56asdasd+a!!5' str
  FROM dual) 
  SELECT regexp_substr(str,'*.{1,5}',1,LEVEL) FROM adc
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(str,'*.{1,5}',1,LEVEL) IS NOT null  `

Comment: А регулярка зачем ? если строго 5 символов то substr более чем достаточно

Comment: `WITH adc as ( SELECT '12345_789563324_56asdasd+a!!5' str FROM dual)
  SELECT substr(str,(level-1)*5+1,5)
    FROM adc
 CONNECT BY substr(str,(level-1)*5+1,5) IS NOT null
 `

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```sql
select res
from (select '123456789qwerty' str from dual) d
cross join xmltable ('
    for $ix in 0 to xs:integer (ceiling (string-length ($str) div 5))-1
    return substring ($str, $ix*5+1, 5)' 
    passing d.str as "str" columns res varchar2 (5) path '.');
```

Результат:

```
RES  
-----
12345
6789q
werty
```

Answer (score 1):

Как предложил [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/681129/#comment999072_681129) в комментарии, работает:

```
WITH adc as ( 
    SELECT '123456789qwerty' str FROM dual
) 
SELECT substr(str,(level-1)*5+1,5) 
FROM adc 
CONNECT BY substr(str,(level-1)*5+1,5) IS NOT null;
```

Вывод:

```
SUBST
-----
12345
6789q
werty
```